# Render OSM tiles using GTRenderer

Tags: geotools

I am trying to render OSM tiles using GTRenderer this way:

```
MapContent map = new MapContent();    
String baseURL = "http://<url>"; // OSM url
TileService service = new OSMService("OSM", baseURL);
TileLayer tileLayer = new TileLayer(service);
map.addLayer(tileLayer);
```

Then I send my `map` to

```
public static void saveImage(final MapContent map,
                                 final String file,
                                 ReferencedEnvelope envelope,
                                 final int imageWidth,
                                 String formatName) {

        GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
        renderer.setMapContent(map);

        java.awt.Rectangle imageBounds = null;
        ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = null;
        try {
            mapBounds = envelope;
            double heightToWidth = mapBounds.getSpan(1) / mapBounds.getSpan(0);
            imageBounds = new java.awt.Rectangle(
                    0, 0, imageWidth, (int) Math.round(imageWidth * heightToWidth));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // failed to access map layers
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(imageBounds.width, imageBounds.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        Graphics2D gr = image.createGraphics();
        gr.setPaint(Color.WHITE);
        gr.fill(imageBounds);

        try {
            renderer.paint(gr, imageBounds, mapBounds);
            File fileToSave = new File(file);
            ImageIO.write(image, formatName, fileToSave);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

However it returns "white space" image.

At the same time, my `saveImage` procedure works fine with a WMS layers. What could be the problem of this?

I ahve also checked my OSM service by

```
Tile t = new OSMTile(
        new OSMTileIdentifier(79234, 40978, new WebMercatorZoomLevel(17), service.getName()),
        service);

BufferedImage image = t.loadImageTileImage(t);
```

It returns correct tile.

**EDITED**

I have also found the following message in the log:

`[pool-2-thread-1] org.geotools.tile Reached tile limit of 128. Returning an empty collection.`

Comment: is it completely white or do the tiles have red crosses on them? If it is the first it is probably a projection or bounding box issue. Can you add the code that sets up your map bounds?

Comment: Map bounds come from REST API method - ReferencedEnvelope[4096257.5 : 4227167.0, 7388652.5 : 7563512.5]. I have two layers in my map: OSM tiles and WMS layer. It is an envelope of the WMS layer in World Mercator coordinates.

If I put both layers to my MapContent, then only WMS is visible. If I put just tiles, then I get completely white image.

Comment: I have also found the following message in the log:
[pool-2-thread-1] org.geotools.tile   Reached tile limit of 128. Returning an empty collection.

Comment: please edit the question with this info, sounds like it might be a zoom level issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ian Turton for his comment about zoom level.
I placed stop-point into TileLayer's draw(Graphics2D graphics, MapContent map, MapViewport theViewport) method and found that my MapViewport is incorrect.
Adding

```
// map is my MapContent object, envelope is a map's ReferencedEnvelope
imageBounds = new java.awt.Rectangle(
                0, 0, imageWidth, (int) Math.round(imageWidth * heightToWidth));
map.getViewport().setScreenArea(imageBounds);
map.getViewport().setBounds(envelope);
```

solves the problem.